# Custom Wordpress "Touch-Like/Mouse Down Drag" slider?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider

I've been searching quite a lot for the past few weeks.
I'm looking for a plugin or some other kind of implementation - Like JQuery.
Below is a little demonstration of what I wish achieved. I was hoping some of you have knowledge on this, as I'm running out of search terms.

What I'm looking for is a slider. As the demonstration shows, I want a horizontal slider with basic article/post information and a picture.

What I've seen a lack of in the ones already tried is the option to use the mouse cursor to either slide left or right.
What I mean is: When pressing and holding the mouse button - the slider slides in the direction your cursor is going. Almost like a touch event on Android or iPhone.

If this isn't available anywhere - Tips on where to start, and how to create this myself would be MUCH appreciated.

I hope I made myself clear. Otherwise let me know. :)

Here's a link to the demonstration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj5Mi.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this one](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/wordpress/?s=cwp). I think it suits your need.